# Finding the conditional probability.

Tags: probability

*Question:*

There are $50$ students in a computer room. $36$ students work on tablets, and $20$ students work on laptops. There are $12$ students who work on none. A teacher chooses a student randomly. What is the probability of this student not working on laptop, given that she has worked on a tablet?

*Solution:*

n(only laptop) = $2$

n(only tablet) = $18$

n(both laptop and tablet) = $18$

n(neither) = $12$

P(not laptop given tablet has been used) = $\frac{P(\text{not laptop and tablet})}{P(\text{tablet})}$

P(not laptop) = $\frac{30}{50}$

P(tablet) = $\frac{36}{50}$

Therefore, P(not laptop given tablet has been used) should be $\frac{3}{5}$, but the answer in my textbook shows that it is $\frac{1}{2}$. How to do to get this answer?

Comment: P(tablet-and-not-laptop)=P(only-tablet)=18/50

Comment: Did you divide by $P(\text{tablet})$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The counting is correct. However, you need to write what these probabilities are.
You have $\mathbb{P}[\text{not laptop} \wedge \text{tablet}] = \mathbb{P}[\text{only tablet}] = n(\text{only tablet}) / 50 = 18/50$.

Next, you need to find $\mathbb{P}[\text{tablet}]$ which is simply $n(\text{tablet})/50 = 36/50$.

Dividing both probabilities gives you $\mathbb{P}[\text{not laptop} \vert \text{tablet}] = 1/2$

Comment: You mean that it is $\frac{\frac{18}{50}}{\frac{36}{50}}$, which simplifies to $1/2$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.